# Is there easy way to install SSH in xampp for windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, xampp

Is there easy way to install SSH in xampp for windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so. Even if you could, you wouldn't have seamless access to apache and mysql as you'd expect on a *nix box.

If you are dead-set, the best bet will be to just install openssh server (http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) and make sure the tools you want to use are in the path. I've always found ssh on a windows machine more trouble than it's worth, though.

Answer (score 1):

You may install OpenSSH for Windows or OpenSSH via Cygwin.  Your choice.