# XAMPP - Windows - SSH2 - Failed to get banner

Tags: php, ssh, xampp

After much stress I was able to get SSH2 working with XAMPP on a Windows 2008 R2 server on a LAN network.  At least I think it's working.  The website I'm using it with is running through port 8880.

How do I determine the port I should use for SSH?  If I set it to the standard port 22 (or anything else), I get the error:

```
Warning: ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to 192.168.1.120 on port 22
```

Or, if I set it to port 8880, I get the following:

```
Warning: ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-2): Failed getting banner
```

Which I thought was interesting, not sure if it helps.

I'm used to setting the port manually in sshd.conf on Linux.  How do I determine or set the port ssh2 uses? Peace out homies.

Comment: have you attempted to connect via the command line?

Comment: It could be in your Windows Firewall settings.  May have to enable access to port 22.

Comment: Firewall is off for this machine.

Comment: I tried connecting through the Xampp shell, but 'ssh'/'sshd' are not available.  It feels like I need to add an entry to php.ini for ssh (or create a separate ini file), but nothing Google'd supports that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Anshu already pointed out that you seem to have a Web server running on port 8880, so SSH cannot possibly be listening on the same port (and IP address).

My best guesses are that either, you don't have SSH running on port 22, or that the Windows firewall blocks port 22. Also, it has been a while since I used XAMPP, but I don't recall it including SSH in the first place? It may be something you need to add to it.

The first step for you should be to check what services are using which port on your Windows server. Open an elevated command prompt, and then run

```
netstat -ab
```

The output will likely be long; you can use more to go through it page by page. Or I usually do this:

```
netstat -ab | find /i "listen"
```

You should find port 8880 listed there, followed by the corresponding program in the next line (probably httpd.exe). Look for a similar line for ssh, probably on port 22. That will tell you definitely which port, if any, SSH is running on.

Comment: Pretty silly of me to click away 100 reputation without trying anything out; however, the provided answer is the kind of direction I wanted.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a SSH server running in XAMPP on port 8880? Or is it the web server which is running on 8880?

Error -2 comes when a non SSH process is listening on the specified port.
For example, connecting to google.com on port 80 using ssh2_connect will give:

```
 php git/a.php 
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-2): Failed getting banner in /media/sf_gitsf/a.php on line 2
PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to google.com in /media/sf_gitsf/a.php on line 2
```

To install SSH server in your XAMPP server, see this

[Is there easy way to install SSH in xampp for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485925/is-there-easy-way-to-install-ssh-in-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: As I state in my question, I have installed SSH2 and it seems to be working.  What I can't figure out is how to set the port # or where to find what the default port is.

Comment: How can you say "it seems to be working" ? Default port is 22.

Comment: I can say that because I'm getting error messages specific to SSH2, rather than "failed to load ssh2 or whatever that error is".  I did load errors continuously throughout the installation process until it finally loaded without problems.  So I'm sure it's working.

Comment: @JamesHuckabone You are getting this error - `  ssh2_connect(): Error starting up SSH connection(-2): Failed getting banner` - which is exactly what I reproduced.