# localhost port connection using putty

Tags: php, putty, libssh2

How to use putty in order to connect to ssh2 port of the xampp (localhost)and generate your own username and password.

I have been using ip address 127.0.0.1 for locahost and port number 22 for ssh2 in the putty software but at the end i get an error while generating the key for username and password. can anyone help me out?

Comment: why do you need to ssh in a local xamp server?

Comment: The client wants it to run on the local server first :|

Comment: i don't think xamp has a build in ssh server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there easy way to install SSH in xampp for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485925/is-there-easy-way-to-install-ssh-in-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: I have installed ssh on the xamp server by using the necessary dll files. when i run the command php -m on the shell module of the xampp, it shows the ssh2 lib so it is installed. That part has already been achieved

Comment: ssh2 lib looks like an ssh client to be used in php. It is not for accepting connections.